# Edit functionality in jQgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jQgrid, i need to give edit functionality to it, when the user clicks on a a particular row, that row details should be displayed in popup...

This is my jquery code in my view

```
    <table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="175"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GetStudents/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['StudentID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'StudentID', index: 'StudentID', width: 150, align: 'center',sortable:false },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150, align: 'center', sortable: true },
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 200, align: 'center', sortable: false}],

            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            width:750,
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'StudentID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: ' My First JQgrid'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like that?
[image: screen]

[See here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)